# Storing CLLocationCoordinates2D in NSMutableArray

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsdata

After some searching, I got the following solution :
[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392909/nsmutablearray-addobject-with-mallocd-struct).

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D* new_coordinate = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
new_coordinate->latitude = latitude;
new_coordinate->longitude = longitude;
[points addObject:[NSData dataWithBytes:(void *)new_coordinate
length:sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)]];
free(new_coordinate);
```

And access it as:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D* c = (CLLocationCoordinate2D*) [[points objectAtIndex:0] bytes];
```

However, someone claims that there is a memory leak here? Can anyone suggest me where is the leak and how to fix it. Further, is there a better way of storing a list of CLLocationCoordinate2D in NSMutableArray? Please give sample code since I am an Objective C newbie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no leak, just a waste of heap memory.

You could just use

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D new_coordinate;
new_coordinate.latitude = latitude;
new_coordinate.longitude = longitude;
[points addObject:[NSData dataWithBytes:&new_coordinate length:sizeof(new_coordinate)]];
```

Answer (score 70):

Here’s another way, using the builtin type `NSValue` which is made for exactly this purpose:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D new_coordinate = { latitude, longitude };
[points addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&new_coordinate objCType:@encode(CLLocationCoordinate2D)]];
```

To retrieve the value use the following code:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D old_coordinate;
[[points objectAtIndex:0] getValue:&old_coordinate];
```

Comment: NSValue is a better choice as this is aimed specifically for this, also you should get rid of struct

Comment: I have created an object with two double properties for holding the latitude and longitude... 
Because i had to add the NSCoding compliance.
It didn't succeed using this suggestion, because while persisting it is considering it as structs, and it can't encode structs.

Comment: @LolaRun On SO follow-up questions are frowned upon. You should post this as a separate question.

Comment: but i'm not asking anything... i'm adding a remark for those who want to store CLLocationCoordinate2D in an array, and "additionally" want to persist this array. That's all... Thank you

Comment: @LolaRun Oh, I see, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks, this was a big help. It would be nice not to have to do all this marshalling by hand though.

Answer (score 51):

Starting with iOS 6, there's the [NSValueMapKitGeometryExtensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/NSValue_MapKit_additions/Reference/Reference.html) for `NSValue`:

```
NSMutableArray *points = [NSMutableArray array];
CLLocationCoordinate2D new_coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
[points addObject:[NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:new_coordinate]];
```

And to retrieve the value:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [[points objectAtIndex:0] MKCoordinateValue];
```

The `NSValueMapKitGeometryExtensions` require **MapKit.framework**
`CLLocationCoordinate2DMake()` requires **CoreLocation.framework**,
so these imports are required:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

Comment: this should be the ACCEPTED ANSWER