# Creating an array of CLLocationCoordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm attempting to get an array of latitude and longitude double values which I have stored in parse.com. I want to be able to convert these back into CLLocationCoordinates which I can then use to create MKPloylines in a custom table view. 
However I'm not too sure how I can store an array of CLLocationCoordinates. 
Here is my code:

```
        _latitudeArray = [object objectForKey:@"latitude"];
        [_parseLatitudeArray addObject:_latitudeArray];

        _longitudeArray = [object objectForKey:@"longitude"];
        [_parseLongitudeArray addObject:_longitudeArray];

        for (int i=0; i < [_parseLatitudeArray count]; i++) {

        _latitude = [self.parseLatitudeArray objectAtIndex:i];
        _longitude = [self.parseLongitudeArray objectAtIndex:i];

            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates [[_latitude count]];

        for (int i = 0; i < [_latitude count]; i++) {

            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
            double latitude = [[_latitude objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
            double longitude = [[_longitude objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
            coordinate.latitude = latitude;
            coordinate.longitude = longitude;
            coordinates[i] = coordinate;
        }
            [_coordinatesArray addObject:coordinates];

        }
        NSLog(@"coordinates array = %@", _coordinatesArray);
```

At first I figured I would be able to do it using [_coordinatesArray addObject:coordinates]; but then realised that would not work!

I may be missing something really basic but any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

EDIT:
property Definitions:

```
@property NSMutableArray *latitudeArray;
@property NSMutableArray *parseLatitudeArray;
@property NSMutableArray *longitudeArray;
@property NSMutableArray *parseLongitudeArray;
@property NSMutableArray *coordinatesArray;
@property NSArray *latitude;
@property NSArray *longitude;
@property CLLocationCoordinate2D *coordinates;
```

Comment: cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577428/storing-cllocationcoordinates2d-in-nsmutablearray

Comment: Couple questions on the code above:  is the adding objects to parseLatitudeArray and parseLongitudeArray in a loop, or else why not just use latitudeArray and Longitude array?  (1) you're nesting a for loop, and reusing `i` in each, guaranteed problem.

Comment: Probably need `(nonatomic, strong)` on your properties

Comment: @mackworth Thanks, I've changed the int for the second for loop, Yeah the parseLatitudeArray and parseLongitudeArray contains Arrays of latitude and longitude double values, respectively

Comment: Right, but they are not array of arrays, correct? And specifically, they are NSArrays of NSStrings, correct? See revised note below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a C-array of structs, wrap each struct into an object and add it to an NSMutableArray. So after you create coordinate, just:

```
[coordinatesArray addObject: [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:coordinate]];
```

And to get the value back out:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
[coordinatesArray[i] getValue:&coordinate];
```

So, assuming that self.latitude and self.longitude are NSArrays of NSStrings:

```
//only property is now
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * locations 

-(void) loadCoordinatesFromParse {
    NSDictionary * parseData;
    //load parseData from Parse here
    NSMutableArray * coordinates = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray * latitudes = [parseData objectForKey:@"latitude"];

    NSArray *longitudes = [parseData objectForKey:@"longitude"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [latitudes count]; i++) {
        double latitude = [latitudes[i] doubleValue];
        double longitude = [longitudes[i] doubleValue];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
        [coordinates addObject: [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:coordinate]];
    }

    NSLog(@"coordinates array = %@", coordinates);
    self.locations = [NSArray arrayWithArray: coordinates];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I get an error - Sending 'CLLocationCoordinate2D [[self->_latitude count]]' to parameter of incompatible type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' Why is this?

Comment: Don't create your array `coordinates` at all.   (Can you post your property defs?)